# Error in PHP file, unable to display output while trying to load PHP file via xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to build a website that would provide me with the value of Pi up to decimal places desired by the user. If the user wants to see value of pi upto 2 decimal place then he/she needs to provide input 2 and value will be displayed as 3.14. I have written a php file but while trying to host the file via xampp I am getting the following errors

This is my code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","whoop_root_596","Ns4td1^9","demo_pi");

$curTime = microtime(true);
$f_val=$_POST["f_val"];

$response = array();
$statement = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pi_value where sl='1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($statement))
{
    $pi_value = $row['vl'];
}

    $pi_value_explode = explode(",", $pi_value);

    $lv="";
    for($i=0;$i<$f_val;$i++)
    {

        $lv=$lv.$pi_value_explode[$i];
        if($i%150==0)
            if($i>150)
            {}
    }
    $timeConsumed = round(microtime(true) - $curTime,3)*1000; 
    $fsval="3.".$lv;
    $sdval="Time Consumed: ".$timeConsumed."ms";

$response = array( array('val1' => $fsval, 'val2' => $sdval) );

echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

These are the errors getting displayed shown in the picture: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u765q.jpg)

kindly provide an effective solution. Any help will be kind enough

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you have to note here. Firstly, you have an access a problem to your Database.This can be fixed be the below method.

In your MySQL command interface, type in

```
CREATE user user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password_txt';
```

And then updae the password with

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password_txt');
```

That should solve your first warning.

Also, on Line 5 where you are receiving the value from the form, make sure id passed is correct. The value is **not received correctly** hence you are shown an error "Undefined Index". **This error means that within your code, there is a variable or constant that has no value assigned to it**

**The last two warning are caused due to the error in the credentials. Fix your user details and that should be resolved by itself.**